# Repeated and misaligned xticks in PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a problem with the xticks in my PGFplot that I'm not sure how to even start troubleshooting. The tick labels are repeated and misaligned; basically they are all over the place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{iso.tsv}
range   X   Y   Z
0--9    9841063 9847764 9840032
10--99  38622   32503   39579
100--999    3116    2672    3197
1000--9999  6054    6019    6057
10000--99999    563 460 553
100000+ 0.1 0.1 0.1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    \def\mystrut{\vphantom{$[1^1$}}     
    \pgfplotstableread{iso.tsv}\mydata


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ymode = log,
    ybar,
    ytick={10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    bar width=.35cm,
    width=15cm,
    height=6cm,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    yminorgrids=false,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={at={(0.99,0.99)},
        anchor=north east,legend columns=1},
    symbolic x coords={0--9,10--99,100--999,1000--9999,10000--99999,100000+},
    x tick label style={font=\mystrut},
    %xticklabels={a,b,c,d,e,f},
    ymin=1,ymax=15000000,
    ylabel={Number of graphs},
    xlabel={Time taken (ms)},
    %enlarge x limits=1
    ]

    \addplot table[x=range,y=X]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=range,y=Y]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=range,y=Z]{\mydata};
    \legend{X, Y, Z}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm sure it must be something quite simple since the plot itself it quite simple, but I cannot seem to find it. Any help much appreciated (once again)!

Comment: Add `xtick=data` to the `axis` options.

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-44GZwoRG_mE/UTOoov9-kHI/AAAAAAAAABA/u74ABm-DFhM/s1600/double_facepalm.jpg

Comment: I removed `xtick=data`it because I thought I was giving the xtick (labels) so they weren't coming from the data, but then ... ugh. In any case, thanks! If you wish to post it as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`symbolic x coords={0--9,10--99,100--999,1000--9999,10000--99999,100000+},` defines only transformations so that the elements of this list are valid input coordinates.

To get the desired result you can use `xtick=data`. To ensure that also the last tick with the very small values will be used add `xmax=100000+`. And of course you have to use `enlarge x limits`.

```
symbolic x coords={0--9,10--99,100--999,1000--9999,10000--99999,100000+},
xtick=data,
xmin=0--9,xmax=100000+,
enlarge x limits={abs={2*(\pgfplotbarwidth+2pt)}},
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{iso.tsv}
range   X   Y   Z
0--9    9841063 9847764 9840032
10--99  38622   32503   39579
100--999    3116    2672    3197
1000--9999  6054    6019    6057
10000--99999    563 460 553
100000+ 0.1 0.1 0.1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \def\mystrut{\vphantom{$[1^1$}}     
    \pgfplotstableread{iso.tsv}\mydata

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ymode = log,
    ybar,
    ytick={10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    bar width=.35cm,
    width=15cm,
    height=6cm,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    yminorgrids=false,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={at={(0.99,0.99)},
        anchor=north east,legend columns=1},
    symbolic x coords={0--9,10--99,100--999,1000--9999,10000--99999,100000+},
    xtick=data,
    xmin=0--9,xmax=100000+,
    enlarge x limits={abs={2*(\pgfplotbarwidth+2pt)}},
    x tick label style={font=\mystrut},
    ymin=1,ymax=15000000,
    ylabel={Number of graphs},
    xlabel={Time taken (ms)},
    ]

    \addplot table[x=range,y=X]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=range,y=Y]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=range,y=Z]{\mydata};
    \legend{X, Y, Z}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to use

```
symbolic x coords={0--9,10--99,100--999,1000--9999,10000--99999,100000+},
xtick={0--9,10--99,100--999,1000--9999,10000--99999,100000+},
xmin=0--9,xmax=100000+,
enlarge x limits={abs={2*(\pgfplotbarwidth+2pt)}},
```

The result is the same as above.

If you add

```
xticklabels={a,b,c,d,e,f},
```

you will get

[image]